# Entering vagrant ssh for the first time in the terminal

Tags: laravel, vagrant, server-configuration

I really don't understand here when I entered vagrant ssh for the first time in the terminal. I'm using laravel Homestead.

output was:

```
 Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

 System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud


Last login: Fri Oct  3 01:24:38 2014 from 10.0.2.2
```

I really don't understand:

```
Last login: Fri Oct  3 01:24:38 2014 from 10.0.2.2 //because its first time I entered vagrant ssh
```

and this:

```
System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last login you see may come from when the Vagrant Box was originally created. For example I just launched a new Vagrant VM based on hashicorp/precise64 and the "last login" showed as September 2012. Subsequent logins will show the last time that *you* logged in.

Regarding the system information being disabled, see this ServerFault question: [System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0 amazon ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/586320/system-information-disabled-due-to-load-higher-than-1-0-amazon-ec2).

Both of the above can safely be considered normal behavior.